# Displaying error in ComponentDidUpdate react native and redux

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-native, error-handling, redux

I am trying to display an error alert when authentication fails using redux. I am doing this in ComponentDidUpdate like so

`if (prevProps.Error !== this.props.Error) {
            this.setState({loading: false})
            this.dropdown.alertWithType('error', 'Error', this.props.Error)
        }`

But the issue is if there is an error after the first attempt, it doesn't display. It doesn't work because `this.props.Error` hasn't changed i.e `prevProps.Error === this.props.Error`.

I have tried `if(this.props.Error) {}`, `if(this.props.Error != '') {}`, they give runtime error.

I know there is a better way to do it but I can't just figure it out. Please help out. Thanks.

The main problem is after the first failure, if the second or subsequent failure returns the same failure message react doesn't know that my error prop has changed, it assumes they are the same. But I want to display error even if it is the same error.

For example first attempt error = 'Authentication failure', second attempt error  = 'Authentication failure'.

Comment: so, if I understood correctly, the first time you execute it it would work nicely but the second time it would not?

Comment: I assume your error message is coming from the server where authentication is taking place.  Have you checked the network log to make sure the data returned from the authentication service is what you're expecting?

Comment: @EnriqueDev yes you are correct. When you attempt to login successively

Comment: if(this.props.Error != '') what is the runtime error here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.Error && nextProps.Error !== ''){
        this.setState({loading: false})
        this.dropdown.alertWithType('error', 'Error', nextProps.Error)
    }
}
```